# What is the fastest way to get the Accelerated Production achievement?

Tags: achievements, magic-duels

The only method I've seen out there uses Animist Awakening in turn 2 (must get 1 land) and in turn 3 (must get 2+ lands). Basically, if you don't get 2x Animist, 1x Fog, a 7-mana creature and/or lands after a few mulligans, you had to restart. In another forum, someone said it took them 7 hours:-(

Is there a more reliable solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### APA Deck (APA = Accelerated Production Achievement)

- 4x Blisterpod (target for Swell; dying gets Eldrazi Scion)
- 3x Gatecreeper Vine (land to hand)
- 2x Gaea's Revenge  (7-mana creatures)
- 3x Plated Crusher
- 4x Axebane Stag
- 4x Fog (spell mastery for Animist)
- 4x Swell of Growth (play 2nd land; spell mastery Animist)
- 2x Gather the Pack (get Blisterpod)
- 2x Nissa's Pilgrimage (play 2nd land; lands to hand)
- 2x Animist Awakening (play 1-3 lands)
- 30x Forest

Options: Primal Bellow (spell mastery), Ruin Processor (7-mana creature)

My APA Deck maximizes your chances on this achievement with multiple combinations of Animist, Swell of Growth, and sacrificed Eldrazi Scions created by dead Blisterpods. It also reduces time - you don't have to mulligan with no lands in your hand if the other cards are right. Play Swell (or Primal) on an opponent's creature to gain spell mastery for Animist.

**Possible sequences:**

- T1: Forest1, Blisterpod
- T2: Forest2, Animist or Swell, Forest3
- T3: Forest4, Animist or Swell, Forest5
- T4: Forest6, sac Eldrazi Scion

**OR:**

- T1: Forest1, Fog
- T2: Forest2, Gatecreeper or Gather
- T3: Forest3, Swell, Forest4, Animist, Forest5, Blisterpod
- T4: Forest6, sac Eldrazi Scion

Contrary to what others have said, Nissa's Pilgrimage is not too slow. It can be played T3 *even without spell mastery*. Start with: 2x Blisterpod, 1x Swell, 1x Pilgrimage, and 1x Forest:

- T1: Forest1, Blisterpod1
- T2: Forest2, Swell, Forest3, Blisterpod2
- T3: Pilgrimage, Forest4
- T4: (draw 7-mana creature), Forest5, sac 2x Eldrazi Scions

With the APA Deck, I was able to get the achievement 3 times in 4 hours. Of course, your mileage may vary. Good Luck!